# c++ expected opening brace as well as redefinition error

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

So I'm trying to define my class in the .h file and write the constructor in the cpp file, like so:

.h file:

```
class Player : protected Character{
    public:
        Player(sf::Vector2f starting_pos, std::list<Object *> *around) : Character(around);
```

.cpp file:

```
Player::Player(sf::Vector2f starting_pos, std::list<Object *> *around){
    //code
}
```

Now the compiler gives both of these errors:

```
character.h:25:90: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
   25 |         Player(sf::Vector2f starting_pos, std::list<Object *> *around) : Character(around);
```

and

```
character.cpp:3:1: error: redefinition of ‘Player::Player(sf::Vector2f, std::__cxx11::list<Object*>*)’
    3 | Player::Player(sf::Vector2f starting_pos, std::list<Object *> *around){
      | ^~~~~~
```

So it seems to me that it wants me to define the code in the .h file AND THEN complains that I didn't do so in the .cpp file. If I put the code directly in the .h file it works, but I don't want to do this.

I'm not sure if these have anything to do with it so here is some more info:

character is an abstract class that inherits from object, and player inherits from character. Also: there is a second error in the cpp file that says that object is not accessible within this context.

I've found a ton of people with a missing closing brace, but nothing about missing opening braces.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your header file you have

```
Player(sf::Vector2f starting_pos, std::list<Object *> *around) : Character(around);
```

Which is causing the error. Since you use an initializer list there, the compiler expects the full function definitions to be there as well. Simply remove the initializer for `Character` from that line, and move it into your C++ file.

.h file

```
Player(sf::Vector2f starting_pos, std::list<Object *> *around);
```

.cpp file

```
Player::Player(sf::Vector2f starting_pos, std::list<Object *> *around) : Character(around) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your ctor-initialiser goes on the *definition*, not the *declaration*, of the constructor.

You confused the compiler, by [effectively] writing a definition (it must be a definition as it has the ctor-initialiser on it) without a `{}` (because you meant for it to be a declaration) … and then later providing [another] definition.